# asp.net method not work in gvresult event rowcommand (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

this is my row command

```
protected void gvResult_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octect-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            Response.End();

            //updateCountDownloaded(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            updateCountDownloaded("1");
        }        
    }

    public void updateCountDownloaded(string iDFile)
    {
        files.updateCountDownloaded(iDFile);
        BindTaskList();
    }
```

and this is the files

```
public void updateCountDownloaded(string IdFile)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = string.Format(
            "UPDATE {0} SET Count = Count + 1 WHERE IdFile = @IdFile"
            ,tableName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdFile", IdFile);
        datalayer.setData(command);
    }
```

when i try run "updateCountDownloaded("1");" in Page_load, it work properly. but why it's doesnt work in rowcommand method? how can i resolv it.
thx in advance

update: no exception, no error, but my table data not updated

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? Any exception or error message? Did you debug your code?

Comment: yes i did, no error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your row command you are flushing the file to the response and finish excecuting further by calling Response.End. What you can try is you can call your function before excecuting the other code as below.

```
protected void gvResult_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
           //updateCountDownloaded(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            updateCountDownloaded("1");

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octect-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            Response.End();

        }        
    }
```

Comment: well it's work when i put it before the other.thank you so much

Comment: but how can i reload the gridview after i update the count?
i have try : 
1. binding gridview after updateCountDownloaded method
2. add method to binding gridview after updateCountDownloaded method
3. add binding gridview in updateCountDownloaded
but no one of them can resolv it.. help me once again :)

Comment: You cannot refresh the grid with this event as the response will be sent to a different window(file in this case). You have to use JavaScript and a new page for this case. Create a new page, which can take the e.CommanArgument as query string. In this page you can write the code for flushing the file. In the grid view command' client click event you need to call a javascript function, which opens this new page in a popup. Then both the code work